# Is it possible to set input field of react-day-picker as required?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-day-picker

I have two DayPickerInput fields in a form and would like to mark them as required field but don't know how. Can anybody please help?

```
        <FormGroup row>
            <Col md="4">
                <Label htmlFor="begin">Begin</Label>
            </Col>
            <Col xs="12" md="8">
                <DayPickerInput value={this.state.begin}
                                format={settings.formatDate} />
            </Col>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup row>
            <Col md="4">
                <Label htmlFor="end">End</Label>
            </Col>
            <Col xs="12" md="8">
                <DayPickerInput value={this.state.end}
                                format={settings.formatDate} />
            </Col>
        </FormGroup>
```

UPDATE: I tried with inputProps:

```
<DayPickerInput inputProps={required} />
```

but got error:

```
ReferenceError: required is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried with inputProps:
>
> ```
> <DayPickerInput inputProps={required} />
> ```
>
> but got error:
>
> ```
> ReferenceError: required is not defined
> ```

This is how to pass object as prop:

```
<DayPickerInput 
   inputProps={
     { required: true }
   } 
/>
```

Comment: how to set name , ref properties?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it at form-validation-level. Checkout Formik:

https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik